# Error al cargar imágenes de icono en netbeans con java swing

Tags: java, java-swing, ant

Llevo días con un problema que no logro entender.

Veamos:
He creado la carpeta "resources" como paquete dentro de mi proyecto.
En ella he cargado una serie de imágenes a tamaño definido, otras para iconos de 60, de 24 ó de 16 de tamaño según el caso.

El problema es que me da error al cargar algunas imágenes, y sin embargo otras las coloca en su sitio sin errores.

Por ejemplo:

```
private void metodoCargarIconos(){
    //fotoCarta = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/bodagua.jpg"));
    fotoCarta = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/aperitivos.jpg"));
}
```

La instrucción comentada, me da error, la otra no.
La carpeta la tengo:

```
resources
    aperitivos.jpg
    bodagua.jpg
```

los errores que me da son los siguientes:

```
Updating property file: C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\build\classes
    compile-single:
    run-single:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
        at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.metodoCargarIconos(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:223)
        at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.<init>(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:82)
        at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.main(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:66)
    C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Línea at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:217):

```
public ImageIcon (URL location) {
    //línea 217
    this(location, location.toExternalForm());
}
```

Línea at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.metodoCargarIconos(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:223):

```
private void metodoCargarIconos(){
    //línea 223
    fotoCarta = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/bodagua.jpg"));
    //fotoCarta = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/aperitivos.jpg"));
}
```

Línea at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:82):

```
public VentanaConfeccionCarta(){
    //línea 82
    metodoCargarIconos();
}
```

Línea at presupuestoboda.VentanaConfeccionCarta.main(VentanaConfeccionCarta.java:66):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    VentanaConfeccionCarta miVentana = new VentanaConfeccionCarta();
}
```

Línea C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1341: The following error occurred while executing this line:

```
<target depends="init,compile-single" name="run-single">
    <fail unless="run.class">Must select one file in the IDE or set run.class</fail>
    //línea del error
    <j2seproject1:java classname="${run.class}"/>
</target>
```

Línea C:\Users\usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\PresupuestoBoda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1

```
<sequential>
            //línea marcada del error
            <java classname="@{classname}" dir="${work.dir}" failonerror="${java.failonerror}" fork="true">
                <classpath>
                    <path path="@{classpath}"/>
                </classpath>
                <modulepath>
                    <path path="@{modulepath}"/>
                </modulepath>
                <upgrademodulepath>
                    <path path="@{upgrademodulepath}"/>
                </upgrademodulepath>
                <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${runtime.encoding}"/>
                <redirector errorencoding="${runtime.encoding}" inputencoding="${runtime.encoding}" outputencoding="${runtime.encoding}"/>
                <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}"/>
                <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs.ide}"/>
                <syspropertyset>
                    <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                    <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
                </syspropertyset>
                <customize/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
```

Alguien me puede decir que me está pasando y porque me arroja ese error ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Podrías mostrar el sitio donde tienes la carpeta resources,  el método `getResource()` devuelve null cuando no encuentra la ruta especificada, sospecho que el error va por ahi

Comment: Te refieres al árbol de directorios del proyecto ? acabo de agregar la imagen. Gracias

Comment: Oye, no me percate, ahí aparece que el error está en la carpeta oneDrive, déjame verla

Comment: Otra cosa, estas haciendo un proyecto?, si quieres hablame al Twitter y yo te ayudo a solucionar problemas que te surjan :D